# How to prevent swift CoreData crash on uninitialized data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

I have a UITableView that stores data in a CoreData entity. The problem is that when retrieving the data in the UITableViewCell, if I try to access cells that has not been accessed yet. The app will crash. How do I prevent that from happening?

I receive the error that says that the array index is out of bounds for this line

```
let news = self.newsArray[indexPath.row] //
```

The app will work fine if everything is accessed and stored in the CoreData before trying to access the cached version by fetching data from the CoreData entity. Right now I want to make it work such that even if some of those data aren't initialized yet, the app will not crash for the user but instead will display nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the array actually has a value in the given index, to do so you can check the number of elements in the array against the value of the index

```
if indexPath.row < self.newsArray.count
{ 
    let news = self.newsArray[indexPath.row]
} else {
    //set details to blank as per example
    //cell.tile.text = ""
}
```

Comment: It stopped crashing, however a new problem came up, it kept reusing data from the old cells instead of displaying nothing. How do I fix that?

Comment: @chiken I add more details for you